# Автоматическое изменение размеров элементов при изменении размеров окна PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, qlcdnumber

Как сделать так, чтобы при изменении размеров окна, изменялись размеры и содержимого.

```
class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(550, 246)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 551, 211))
        self.lcdNumber.setProperty("intValue", 999)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вставьте виджет в макет:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 551, 211))
        self.lcdNumber.setProperty("intValue", 999)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lcdNumber) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(550, 246)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть, оно работает потому что в лаяуте?

Comment: @ИванКакуркин да